# how to define custom sql type enum field

Tags: go, enums, go-gorm

I want to define custom sql type `enum` like this:

```golang
package db

import (
    "database/sql/driver"
    "github.com/spf13/cast"
)

type Enum int64

func (e Enum) Value() (driver.Value, error) {
    return int64(e), nil
}

func (e *Enum) Scan(v any) error {
    *e = Enum(cast.ToInt64(v))
    return nil
}
```

And I want use the following：

```
package db_test

import (
    "db"
    "gorm.io/driver/sqlite"
    "gorm.io/gorm"
    "testing"
)

type StatusEnum = db.Enum

const (
    StatusEnumEnable StatusEnum = iota
    StatusEnumDisable
)

// this is error because this type alias can not define new method
//func (e *StatusEnum) String() string{
//  if v,ok := StatusEnumMap[*e];ok{
//      return v
//  }
//  return "unknown"
//}

var StatusEnumMap = map[StatusEnum]string{
    StatusEnumEnable:  "Enable",
    StatusEnumDisable: "Disable",
}

type module struct {
    Status StatusEnum
}

func TestEnum(t *testing.T) {
    db, _ := gorm.Open(sqlite.Open(":memory:"))

    db.AutoMigrate(&module{})

    db.Model(&module{}).Create(&module{Status: StatusEnumDisable})

    var out *module
    // SELECT * FROM `modules` WHERE status=1 ORDER BY `modules`.`status` LIMIT 1
    db.Debug().Model(&module{}).Where("status=?", StatusEnumDisable).First(&out)

    t.Log(out)
    t.Log(StatusEnumMap[out.Status])
    //t.Log(out.Status.String())
}
```

Now I'm using it like this `StatusEnumMap[EnumValue]` when I want the string format. I think `value.String()` is more elegant and simple. `fmt` formatting can also print strings instead of numbers.

How can I better implement this feature? Thank you for your suggestions.

The above question has been answered by @Zeke Lu.

Another little problem, If I did not used `Valuer` and delete the `String` method, the sql condition `status=1` will be `status="1"`, why? Whether the query performance of sql will be affected if the type inconsistency in mysql.

The second problem：just is gorm debug info. Actual execute sql is `status=1`. See [gorm-issue](https://github.com/go-gorm/gorm/issues/6297#issue-1697033133)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you don't need to implement the `Valuer` and `Scanner` interfaces if the underlying type is `int64`. If that's true, the type `Enum` is not needed. The following example works without `Enum`:

**Note**: I modified your demo slightly to implement the `Stringer` interface  on type `StatusEnum` instead of `*StatusEnum`.

```golang
package db_test

import (
    "testing"

    "gorm.io/driver/sqlite"
    "gorm.io/gorm"
)

type StatusEnum int64

const (
    StatusEnumEnable StatusEnum = iota
    StatusEnumDisable
)

var StatusEnumMap = map[StatusEnum]string{
    StatusEnumEnable:  "Enable",
    StatusEnumDisable: "Disable",
}

func (e StatusEnum) String() string {
    if v, ok := StatusEnumMap[e]; ok {
        return v
    }
    return "unknown"
}

type module struct {
    Status StatusEnum
}

func TestEnum(t *testing.T) {
    db, _ := gorm.Open(sqlite.Open(":memory:"))

    db.AutoMigrate(&module{})

    db.Model(&module{}).Create(&module{Status: StatusEnumDisable})

    var out *module
    // SELECT * FROM `modules` WHERE status=1 ORDER BY `modules`.`status` LIMIT 1
    db.Debug().Model(&module{}).Where("status=?", StatusEnumDisable).First(&out)

    t.Log(out)
    t.Logf("status value: %d, status string: %s", out.Status, out.Status)
}
```

The output is:

```
&{Disable}
status value: 1, status string: Disable
```

Please note that the first one is `&{Disable}` now. It's `&{1}` before.

Comment: Oh, I didn't try that, thanks.